# How to minimize using hot corner in ubuntu gnome?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I want to enable minimization of the currently active window in the [Custom Hot Corners](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1362/custom-hot-corners/) extension.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Install `xdotool` and add the following in Custom Hot Corners:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

Also see the following screenshot:

[image: Custom Hot Corners]