# Where is the config file for "Hot Corner" in gnome 42.5?

Tags: gnome, gestures

I've have "Hot Corner" enabled via **Settings** ... **Multitasking** ... *General*

I want to tweak the sensitivity or size of the trigger area so I don't launch *Activities Overview* inadvertently as frequently as I do now.

"Hot Corner" options are not in [**gnome-tweaks**](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/gnome-tweaks). This [question references an extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918647/make-gnome-hot-corner-delay) which extensions.gnome.org says is Incompatible and the author no longer maintains. And so far [none of these results reference a config file](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22Hot+Corner%22+%5Bgnome%5D) or key which I would prefer to an extension anyway.

My env:

- **GNOME** 42.5 / X11
- **Ubuntu** 22.04
- `gnome-tweaks` 42.beta

[image]

Comment: It's extremely unlikely anything in GNOME Shell that's not configurable via GNOME Tweaks will be configurable by an editable text file. There might be a gsettings/dconf key, but I'd guess it might be on/off at best.

Comment: Thank you, guiverc. I'm on GNOME 42.5. This info is in my title and I'll add it and U22.04 to the body. Any other release details I should include to improve my Q?  

A `gsettings`/`deconf` key helps narrow my search - much obliged, muru. `xdotool` is another avenue noted in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346680/how-to-minimize-using-hot-corner-in-ubuntu-gnome). 

@ on or off, I recall there being options for 0) delay before triggering and 1) trigger area size in pixels, but not the specific tools, keys, parameters, and it might've been for another desktop environment.